# Ionic Cordova Device UUID

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Hi i am developing a hybrid app using the Ionic framework and Cordova. I am looking to use the device uuid as an ID so i have added the cordova device plugin. Additionally i am using the NG-Cordova wrapper for calling my cordova plugins. However whenever i run my app in the xcode Simulator or on an actual Ipad all i get is {{uuid}} .

There does not seem to be any error message i can only assume that the Device Plugin is not working.

i have put my code below however im not sure this is the issue, Has anyone had this issue before and if so how did they work around it?

Controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', []).controller('DashCtrl', function(
$scope, $state, $cordovaDevice) {
var init = function() {
    console.log("initializing device");
    try {
        $scope.uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error " + err.message);
        alert("error " + err.$$failure.message);
    }
};
init();
```

})

Html

```
<ion-view title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <h1>Dash</h1>
    {{uuid}}
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(
                    true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
        });
    }).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
            .state('tab', {
                url: "/tab",
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
            })
            // Each tab has its own nav history stack:
            .state('tab.dash', {
                url: '/dash',
                views: {
                    'tab-dash': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
                        controller: 'DashCtrl'
                    }
                }
            });
        // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');
    });
```

Comment: is that a typo or are you really missing ng-controller ??

Comment: I dont need ng-controller because its called in the route... sorry should have made that clear

Comment: updated the question to include my app.js file

Comment: I don't see that you've included ngCordova into your angular.module directive.  Is there more code we're missing?

Comment: When i include ngCordova into the app it just gives a blank screen and doesnt work... i think this may be the cause of my problems, if i create a brand new project and include the ngCordova in my module everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason behind my issue was due to using a custom build of ngCordova.

if i just the normal or Minified version of ngcordova it works perfectly.

Thanks for all the help.